# .net core 3 with Nginx reverse proxy redirect to port 5001, but no page is loaded

Tags: nginx, .net

I'm trying to setup an ubuntu 18.04 droplet to run .Net Core 3.1 Web app.  I'm following [this](https://medium.com/@mliyanage/host-asp-net-core-web-api-and-mysql-with-nginx-on-a-digitalocean-5-ubuntu-18-04-droplet-b4f50a19ca6) tutorial.

So far I have the nginx working (or at least I can see the nginx welcome page) if I write the droplet IP in a browser.
I have created the /var/www/html/example.com folder with my .Net Core application inside and its working.
I have change my dns cache (on my local machine) to redirect example.com to my droplet IP.

But when I put example.com in the browser I get redirected to example.com:5001 with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The nginx access.log got this:

186.XXX.X.XX - - [03/May/2020:03:07:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 307 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"

This is my nginx configuration
/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com *.example.com;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}
```

I'm pretty new in cloud systems and server setup so I'm kind of lost. I just want to get a server working, so I can upload some code and practice .Net Core coding. So any help would be nice!

Thank u in advice!

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out what I was missing. I was running de app without specifing the port number in program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls(new[] { "http://0.0.0.0:5001" }); // now the Kestrel server will listen on port 5001!
            });
```